# delete and create folder before uploading files into the folder using Multer

Tags: rest, post, fs, multer

I am trying to upload files into a folder using multer and it is working fine.
Now my requirement is before it upload file into 'uploads' folder, it should delete it first, create the upload folder and then upload it.
I just want to do operation on uploaded file not on the previous data stored.
Code:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
const uploadPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "uploads");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads/",
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/fileupload", upload.array("docs", 10), async function(
  req,
  res,
  next
) {
  let result = {};
  try {

    if (fs.existsSync(uploadPath)) {
      fs.removeSync(uploadPath);
      console.log("dir removed");
      fs.ensureDirSync(uploadPath);
      console.log("directory created");
    } else {
      fs.ensureDirSync(uploadPath);
      console.log("directory created");
    }

    const uploadObj = util.promisify(upload.any());
    await uploadObj(req, res);

    result.message = "Upload successful";
    res.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    console.error("Upload error");
  }
});
```

I tried to make the code async also but after that it is not uploading any file. What I understood is upload.array is a middleware so it run first whenever POST request is called and rest run after this. So multer is uploading the data in existing folder and then once it comes inside the POST fs is deleting and creating it again.
how can I make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work.
As multer is a middleware it executes first then the rest code. So i put that middleware in my code instead at the header. Below is the full code.

```
const create_upload_dir = () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(uploadPath)) {
    fs.removeSync(uploadPath);
    console.log("dir removed");
    fs.ensureDirSync(uploadPath);
    console.log("directory created");
  } else {
    fs.ensureDirSync(uploadPath);
    console.log("directory created");
  }
  return Promise.resolve("Success");
};


const multer = require("multer");

const upload_documents = () => {
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./uploads/",
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

  return upload;
};

router.post("/fileupload", async function(req, res, next) {
    let result = {};
    try {
      await create_upload_dir();

      const upload = upload_documents();

      upload.array("docs", 10);

      const uploadObj = util.promisify(upload.any());

      await uploadObj(req, res);

      console.log("upload successful");

      res.send("Upload successful");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      console.error("Upload error");
    }
  });
```

notice I put in try block

> upload.array("docs", 10);

instead of

> router.post("/fileupload",upload.array("docs", 10), async function(req, res, next)